# Replicação não Funciona

Tags: mysql

Na minha replicação configurada, o Slave não executa as instruções do Master e também não ignora as tabelas e o banco que eu especifiquei.
Estou utilizando o `MySql 5.5`

Segue o Arquivo `my.cnf`

```
server-id       = 3                                     
relay-log       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.log    
log_slave_updates = 1                                   
log_bin         = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log          

binlog-do-db    = dbSlave                             
replicate-rewrite-db = dbMaster1->dbSlave             

replicate-ignore-db = dbMaster2                         

replicate_wild_do_table = dbSlave.tb1         
replicate_wild_do_table = dbSlave.tb2              
replicate_wild_do_table = dbSlave.tb3           

replicate_wild_ignore_table = dbSlave.tb4
replicate_wild_ignore_table = dbSlave.tb5
```

Comando `SHOW STATUS SLAVE`

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 10.0.xx.xx
                  Master_User: usuario
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000343
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 470355
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000038
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4573
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000343
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: dbMaster2
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: dbSlave.tb1,dbSlave.tb2,dbSlave.tb3
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: dbSlave.tb4,dbSlave.tb5
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 470355
              Relay_Log_Space: 4729
              Until_Condition: None
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
             Master_Server_Id: 1
```

Comment: Só por via das duvidas, você fez o restart no serviço do MySql em seu servidor/máquina?

Comment: Sim, no log mysql-relay-bin.0000XX do meu Slave até exibi o SQL que foi excutado no meu Master. Mas não acontece nada.